# Sikuli wrapper for C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, sikuli

I am looking for a Sikuli wrapper that I can use in my C# WebDriver scripts.  I tried using this http://sourceforge.net/projects/sikuli4net/ but it was built against .Net Framework 4.5.1 and we are not sure if we upgrade from our existing .Net Framework 4.5 to version 4.5.1, our other .Net solutions will work.  Any inputs will be greatly appreciated.

p.s. there's another Sikuli wrapper called Sikuli Integrator, but it requires Java 6, which is vulnerable in terms of security.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

how about try to clone source code and compile it with .Net 4.5?